# How to get an editable environment variable file in production build in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a  constant service which keeps all the constants for the app including base url of backend.

```
export class ConstantsService {
  public BACKEND_URL  = 'http://10.0.27.176:8000/';
}
```

This is less flexible because I can't change the `BACKEND_URL` after building the project. I want a file which exports `BACKEND_URL` and is also present into production build so that I can change `BACKEND_URL` after build as well.

I did this:

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment.prod';
...
export class ConstantsService {
  public BACKEND_URL = environment.url;
}
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url: 'http://10.0.27.176:8000/';
};
```

But the problem is this environment.prod.ts is not present in the build.

Can someone please tell me how do I achieve this?

**Edit:** 
Follwing is my bg build --prod output. **There is no environment.prod.ts**

```
Date: 2018-09-11T11:52:10.945Z
Hash: 96c48ccf441d2f7a204f
Time: 9301ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.3af8bf49d802296d8ab1.js (scripts) 174 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} 0.d9c510e0e0d04dde4c78.js () 1.27 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} runtime.a18a7eb7c080a20cb142.js (runtime) 1.84 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.0260add3f34224e145b6.css (styles) 5.58 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.92108b287fe28032870b.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} main.4bbca11d5e8a6cdb36c0.js (main) 316 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes, exactly. I am asking to change change app variables in **after** build. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: One option I've seen used beforeis: In your `environment.prod.ts` file, set the value of `BACKEND_URL` to a replaceable token (e.g. `%BACKEND_URL%`) and then do a replace-in-files type of build-step using a post-build script, for example. I'm not suggesting that this is clean, but it's *a* solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is very useful when having multiple environments where you can edit config but use the same build.

It makes no sense to rebuild the entire app in order to change configuration, especially not in an enterprise environment where you need to manage deployments and want build numbers to align or have an app where you host the same app in multiple locations, ex for private cloud scenarios, where a SaaS-hosting (same app for all clients) is not desired for various reasons.

We're using APP_INITIALIZER form Angular to load environment-specific variables on app startup to fetch data.

Have a look at the documentation here: https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

The URL for where to fetch data data is usually best to do by convention, we let the build system drop a .json file with environment specific settings at the relative path /assets/config/env.json which is loaded by the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build --prod?
Check your build configuration. It should replace the standard environment.ts by environment.prod.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class, you're supposed to instantiate it.

This would mean, for instance, that you would have this :

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  ...new ConstantsService('http://10.0.27.176:8000/')
};

export class ConstantsService {
  constructor(public BACKEND_URL: string) {}
}
```

But if you didn't know, a constant means that you can't change the memory reference of a variable, e.g. doing

```
const x = 1;
x = 2;
```

But since you manipulate an object, this is a single memory reference. So nothing prevents you from doing this (although it is bad practice)

```
expont const environment = {
  production: false
}

environment.production = true;
```

Tu fully answer your question, environment files are used when you build your application. You should always import the default one, `environment.ts`.

At build time, you can use command parameters to chose which environment to use.

Angular 5

```
ng build --env prod
```

Angular 6

```
ng build -c prod
```

This will change your default environment file with the one provided. `prod` is another default one, but you can create as much as you want in your `angular[-cli].json` file.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. What I am asking is to have one config file in build...which exports the app variables. If I change the variables in that file (**after build**) variables should be changed thrughout the app

Comment: I understood pretty well, I've told you how to do it and told you it was bad practice (start of the answer, especially 2nd and 3rd piece of code).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same thing, but could not find any solution. So I made my own.

create `config.js` and `config.prod.js` in your `src` folder.

```
var BASE_API_URL = 'X';
```

Then edit `angular.json` file, there is a `fileReplacements` array for each environment (only `production` if you don't have any custom environments)

```
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/config.js",
                  "with": "src/config.prod.js"
                }
              ],
```

And then add `src/config.js` to the `assets` array in `angular.json`.

```
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/config.js",
              "src/Web.config"
            ],
```

And then put `<script src="config.js"></script>` in your `index.html` file.

Then build,Now you have `config.js` file in the dist folder that is editable.

Comment: That works but APP_INITIALIZER works better for this as the rest of your app won't load until that config has been read properly. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you will only need to import from environment.ts and it will be replaced at build time for different environment configurations.

To enable environment.prod.ts you need either run `ng build --prod` or `ng build --configuration=production`. If you look at your `angular.json` file you will see the following part:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "src": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "replaceWith": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true
    }
  }
```

Which you will also be able to create your own configurations like it. For example, if you create another enviroment.ts called environment.test.ts - it may be used like this:

```
    "test": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "src": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "replaceWith": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": false,
      "outputHashing": "none",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": false,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": false,
      "extractLicenses": false,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": false
    }
```

And in your environment.test.ts -

```
export const environment = {
  production: false, // this way you won't have to enable production mode for developing
  url: 'http://10.0.27.176:8000/';
};
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I am asking... once the build files is created, how can I change some application variables

Comment: you are not seeing the environment file after build because it has been complied and bundled in js file. If you search the api Url you set up in your main.js you will see it. You can always use some post build script to make change to it, but it's bad practice